# Can any Android apps log my clipboard and upload it to their server without my permission?

Tags: android, clipboard

Everyday we copy paste texts that are sometime very important and we don't want anyone to see that. Can any Android app log our clipboard and upload it to their server without my permission?
I have checked settings to disable permission of an app that provides clipboard service but I didn't see any permission about it.

Answer (score -1):

Asking this question is like asking whether apps that you install on windows can hack you. The answer is that while the answer is supposed to be no, in reality it is a resounding yes. Somewhere in the world, there is going to be at least one hacker who can exploit Android's local AV systems. It's called spyware. So while it is SAFER to stick with the google play store, if you are concerned about this I would recommend installing a secure AV or switching to a more secure OS. And even then, you are never going to be ENTIRELY safe from spyware attacks.